# how to change style to error, input, and label to formhelper in cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp

if i want to changes the tag and style of all the elements in formhelper with cakephp 2.x

example

$this->Form->input("name")
generate:

```
<div class="input number">
<label for="AfiliadoCedula">Cedula</label>
<input name="data[Afiliado][cedula]" type="number" value="12" id="AfiliadoCedula">
<div class="error-message">name error</div>
</div>
```

change for:

```
<div class="input number **myclassfieldset**">
<label for="AfiliadoCedula" class="**myclasslabel**">Cedula</label>
<input name="data[Afiliado][cedula]" type="number" class="**myclassinput**" value="12"  id="AfiliadoCedula">
<**label** class="error-message **myclasserror**">name error</**label**>
</div>
```

Thnks for your help a lot!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$this->Form->input("name", array(
                          'div' => array('class' => '**myclassfieldset**'),
                          'label' => array('class' => '**myclasslabel**'),
                          'class' => '**myclassinput**'
));
```

Comment: thanks, one question more. if you see i want to use label instead of div in the error message. how can i do that and thanks for your help?

Comment: @CharlyPalencia it is not possible to change error, to do you have change the core(not good), instead you can use javascript to replace that div with label